# I want to count the number of Palindromes in a text file using python. but this program I wrote is giving me 0 instead of 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, count, palindrome

I want to count the number of Palindromes in a text file using python. but this program I wrote is giving me 0 instead of 2
Text file:

```
Tattarrattat was coined by writer James Joyce in a book called Ulysses.
Aibohphobia is a joke term used to describe the fear of palindromes.
```

Program:

```
filename = "palindrome_test.txt"
x=0
#initiation
with open('palindrome_test.txt','r') as text:
    for line in text: #for loop
        line = line.split() #to split the line into words
        for i in range(0,100):
            if line[i] == line[i][::-1]: 
                x +=1 #increment

print(x)
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `palindrome_test.txt`

Comment: The code works fine for me... There must be an issue with the contents of your text file.

Comment: text file content: Tattarrattat was coined by writer James Joyce in a book called Ulysses.
Aibohphobia is a joke term used to describe the fear of palindromes

Comment: Please [edit] the content into the question, don't just put it as a comment.

Comment: Running your code against your text file doesn't print 0. [It raises an `IndexError`, because there aren't 100 words on the line, and it leaves `x` as 2, not 0, because it counts the pallindrome `a` twice.](https://repl.it/repls/ConcreteYellowProperty)

Comment: Meanwhile, you've tagged this both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`. Which one are you actually asking about?

Comment: @abarnert For me, it's showing 0. Posted the content of the text file.

Comment: `'Aibohphobia'` is _not_ a palindrome, according to your definition, because `'A'!='a'`.

Comment: So, it's like if I'm changing the upper bound on range, my answer varies. Any idea how can I replace the upper bound by exact number of words in the text?

Comment: @kapa You can do `for i in range(len(words)):`. But why do you even want a number in a range? Why not just `for word in words:`?

Comment: @abarnert Yea, I should rather use for word in words: . Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code. First, the number of words in a line is, in general, not 100. Second, a capital letter is not equal to the corresponding lowercase letter. Here's a corrected version of your program:

```
count = 0 # x is never a good name
with open('palindrome_test.txt','r') as text:
    for line in text: 
        words = line.lower().split() #split the lowercased line into words
        for w in words:
            if w == w[::-1]: 
                count += 1 #increment
```

Note that the word 'a' is also a palindrome (it happens twice in your text).

You can replace the for loop with a list comprehension to get a better-looking program:

```
count = 0
with open('palindrome_test.txt','r') as text:
    for line in text: 
        words = line.lower().split() #split the lowercased line into words
        count += sum(w == w[::-1] for w in words)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked for me :). Thanks for the explanation